# Laravel - Seeding Many-to-Many Relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, factory, faker, laravel-seeding

I have a **`users`** table and a **`roles`** table that has a **many-to-many** relationship. These two tables are connected to a junction table called **`role_user`**.

[This is a model of the tables and its connections.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vw43I.png)

Below are the Models in my Laravel project:

**User**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    }
}
```

**Role**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

Below is the Factory file in the Laravel project:

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'password' => $password ?: $password = bcrypt('secret'),
    ];
});

$factory->define(App\Role::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'role' => $faker->realText($maxNbChars = 2),
        'description' => $faker->realText($maxNbChars = 20),
    ];
});
```

Below is the Seed file in the Laravel project:

```
public function run()
{
    factory(App\User::class, 50)->create()->each(function ($u) {
        $u->roles()->save(factory(App\Role::class)->make());
    });

    factory(App\Role::class, 20)->create()->each(function ($u) {
        $u->users()->save(factory(App\User::class)->make());
    });
}
```

This should populate the **`users`** table and the **`roles`** table but how do I go about populating the **`role_user`** table? (I don't have a Model file for the junction table.)

I'm very new at this so any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You can use [`attach()` or `sync()` method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) on a many-to-many relationship.

There are multiple ways you can approach this. Here one of them:

```php
// Populate roles
factory(App\Role::class, 20)->create();

// Populate users
factory(App\User::class, 50)->create();

// Get all the roles attaching up to 3 random roles to each user
$roles = App\Role::all();

// Populate the pivot table
App\User::all()->each(function ($user) use ($roles) { 
    $user->roles()->attach(
        $roles->random(rand(1, 3))->pluck('id')->toArray()
    ); 
});
```

Comment: Can anyone explain why it chooses random between 1 and 3 instead of random between 1 and 20 (As there are 20 records in Roles, not 3)?

Comment: Could also say $roles->random(rand(1, $roles->count())) to get from 1 to the max available amount of roles

Comment: This will attach between 1 and 3 random roles to the user. NOT choose a role between id 1 and 3!
I guess @peterm wanted to show how to limit (min and max) the number of roles you want to attach.

Answer (score 14):

Another way is to use saveMany() function

```
public function run()
{

   factory(App\User::class,3)->create();

   $roles = factory(App\Role::class,3)->create();

   App\User::All()->each(function ($user) use ($roles){
      $user->roles()->saveMany($roles);
   });
}
```

Comment: This is going to attach 3 new roles separately to each user, it is not the real many-to-many relation mockup, but many-to-one in fact.

Answer (score 7):

A much cleaner method can be: after you define the factory for App\User and App\Roles you can call the **afterCreating** method like this:

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, function ...);
$factory->define(App\Role::class, function ...);

$factory->afterCreating(App\User::class, function ($row, $faker) {
    $row->roles()->attach(rand(1,20));
});
```

Then in Seeds you first create the roles, then the users

```
public function run()
{
    factory(App\Role::class, 20)->create();
    factory(App\User::class, 50)->create();
}
```

Now you have 50 users each of them with one role attached.

Answer (score 6):

Just for a seeder you can use something like this:

```
   for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) {
        $user = factory(App\User::class)->create();

        $role = factory(App\Role::class)->create();

        DB::table('role_user')->insert([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'role_id' => $role->id
        ]);
    }
```

But normally you need to define relation like has many through    https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Then you will be able to use:

```
$user->roles()->save($role);
```

Answer (score 1):

Better to use this structure:

```php
App\Role::factory()->count(20)->create();

// Populate users
App\User::factory()->count(50)->create();

// Getting all roles and saving them to variable is not too good idea.
// Instead, get count of rows.
$rolesCount = App\Role::count();

// Populate the pivot table
App\User::all()->each(function ($user) use ($rolesCount) { 
    $user->roles()->attach(
        App\Role::all()->random(rand(1, $rolesCount))->pluck('id')->toArray()
    );
});
```

Comment: "Getting all roles and saving them to variable is not too good idea" why not? There are only 20 values, this is a negligible use of resources. Also this whole method is obsolete with modern versions of Laravel; `factory()` helper isn't even there any more.

Comment: We don't need all the records stored in the variable to quantify them. Instead, we can immediately grab a count of records. if the person who asked the question uses the @peterm's solution elsewhere he will have performance issues (in this case here is 20 values, but I think, we should give universal answers).

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 9 and beyond:

```php
$roles = Role::factory()->count(10)->create();

$user->roles()->attach($roles);
```