# How to populate pivot table in laravel??

Tags: php, laravel, pivot-table, factory, seed

I wrote factories for posts and categories and the work perfectly. But i can't find a way to populate the category_post table to test the ManyToMany relation between them.

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried attaching the record? pivot tables filled with content when you attach the correct relationship between two entities. Refer to this on usage: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Here we have many people eager to help, not all of them are telepaths. Since you have php tag, perhaps adding some code of what you tried might help.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45269146/laravel-seeding-many-to-many-relationship

Comment: where you want to populate in `view` or `database` ??

Answer (score 6):

The [attach](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) method accepts an array as a second parameter for saving pivot table data:

```
$post = Post::find(1);

$category = Category::find(1);

$post->categories()->attach($category->getKey(), ['foo' => 'bar']);
```