# Nested database seeding for Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Laravel 8 has some changes in database seeding. I want to seed some related models with database seeder.
There are three models: `User, Post, Comment`.
A user has many posts, and a post has many comments.
Now I want to create some users with some related posts and some comments related to the post.
I can only seed some user and the related posts, but not comments related to the posts.
I have the code below:

```
User::factory(10)->hasPosts(rand(5, 10))->create();
```

It created 10 users and 5 to 10 related posts for each user. What can I do to seed the comments? Can I do it in the single line or do I need to to to new line?
Note: I have created the factory for each model.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45269400/7574023) may help you

Comment: @boolfalse things are much simplified in Laravel 8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try

```php
User::factory(10)->has(
    Post::factory(random_int(5,10))
        ->has(Comment::factory(random_int(2,3)))
)->create();
```